# How to get Order Attributes List without using id in Magento2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I need to get all the attributes from order,quote, invoice, shipment like products and customers.

Comment: Do you want get all orders or only specific one?

Comment: we will get products attributes list in magento2. in same way i need to get for orders

Comment: Oh I see. https://mage2.pro/t/topic/655